# How can i run 2 functions (while(True)) in the same time?

Tags: python

How can i run 2 functions (while(True)) in the same time?

i have 2 functions client_telegram.run_until_disconnect() and tkinter.Tk.mainloop(). How can i execute in parallel..
for e.g. i want to modify a variable from tkinter, but in the same time the 'client_telegram' should working ( to hear messages from telegram API)

```
client_telegram = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)
client_telegram.start()
client_telegram.run_until_disconnected()
top = tkinter.Tk()
top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to run two functions 'in parallel', more precisely concurrently its best to use threading. The concept of threading in general is to manage ana organize the execution of many processes simultaneously.

In your example, if the two functions you want to run in parallel don't work with any share resource or variable, then you don't any synchronization and you can launch the two functions concurrently with no problems in this way:

```
import threading

t1 = threading.Thread(target=top.mainloop)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=client_telegram.start)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

If the two functions need synchronization, then there are many concepts like Locks and semaphores you can use to control execution of threads.